# Como editar uma lista em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Quero editar um cadastro de um cliente no qual já consigo criar cadastro, consultar e remover. Mas não faço ideia de como editar apenas alguns itens sem que os outros sejam perdidos.

```
class Program
{
    static List<Cliente> ClienteList = new List<Cliente>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int op = -1;

        while (op != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digite 1 para cadastrar: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite 2 para consultar: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite 3 para remover cadastro");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite 4 para editar cadastro: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite 0 para sair: "); 

            op = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            {
                if (op == 1)
                {
                    CadastroCliente();
                }
                else
                    if (op == 2)
                    {
                        ConsultaCadaCli();
                    }
                    else
                        if (op == 3)
                        {
                            RemoverCadastro();
                        }
                        else
                            if (op == 4)
                            {
                                EditarCliente();
                            }
            }

        }
    }
    public static void CadastroCliente()
    {
        Cliente cli = new Cliente();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome: ");
        cli.Nome = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o CPF: ");
        cli.Cpf = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o telefone: ");
        cli.Tel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Digiete o endereco: ");
        cli.End = Console.ReadLine();

        ClienteList.Add(cli);

    }
    public static void ConsultaCadaCli()
    {
        int Consulta;
        Console.WriteLine("Digite seu CPF");
        Consulta = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var ConsultCadastro = ClienteList.Where(c => c.Cpf.Equals(Consulta)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (ConsultCadastro != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nome: " + ConsultCadastro.Nome);
            Console.WriteLine("CPF: " + ConsultCadastro.Cpf);
            Console.WriteLine("Telefone: " + ConsultCadastro.Tel);
            Console.WriteLine("Endereco: " + ConsultCadastro.End);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cliente nao cadastrado");
        }
    }
    public static void RemoverCadastro()
    {
        int RemCadast;
        Console.WriteLine("Digite seu CPF");
        RemCadast = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var RCli = ClienteList.Where(r => r.Cpf.Equals(RemCadast)).FirstOrDefault();

        if(RCli != null)
        {
            ClienteList.Remove(RCli);
            Console.WriteLine("Cadastro removido com sucesso. ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cliente nao cadastrado");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amanda, já estou preparando uma resposta e algumas melhorias no seu código.

Comment: @Amanda veja o [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma das respostas como a que mais lhe ajudou. E pode votar em todas as perguntas e respostas que achar úteis no site todo, inclusive aqui.

Answer (score 9):

É quase um misto de cadastrar e consultar. Você precisa achar o cliente como na consulta e pedir novos dados como no cadastro. Só que ao invés de adicionar você altera os dados do cliente encontrado:

```
public static void EditarCliente()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite seu CPF");
    int Consulta = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var cli = ClienteList.Where(c => c.Cpf.Equals(RemCadast)).FirstOrDefault();

    if(cli != null) {
        Console.WriteLine("CPF: " + cli.Cpf);
        Console.WriteLine("Nome: " + cli.Nome);
        Console.WriteLine("Telefone: " + cli.Tel);
        Console.WriteLine("Endereco: " + cli.End);

        Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome: ");
        cli.Nome = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o telefone: ");
        cli.Tel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Digiete o endereco: ");
        cli.End = Console.ReadLine();
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Cliente nao cadastrado");
    }
}
```

Você pode ver a [código completo funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EIY3mU) com algumas pequenas melhorias que você pode fazer, mas ainda com alguns problemas (e [no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WiWH9r)). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/FillList2.cs).

## Algumas melhorias possíveis

Não estou dizendo que que você deva fazer nesse trabalho. Provavelmente está além do que você aprendeu e provavelmente o esforço é muito grande.

Poderia permitir que os dados mostrados sejam aproveitados para edição durante a entrada de dados, o que complicaria bem a lógica que está fazendo. Mas basicamente é isto.

Eu entendo que essa foi uma implementação ingênua de um cadastro. Se fosse fazer algo real o código teria que fazer muito mais. Poderia verificar erros que podem acontecer, duplicidade de cadastro, fazer validações, não usar tipos de dados ruins como `int` para telefone e CPF (dados que não serão usados em cálculo devem ser sempre `string`), etc. Teria muitas alterações para ficar algo realmente funcional, mas não adianta melhorar só um pouco para algo que está claramente sendo usado como aprendizado.

Fiz só algumas mudanças para manter consistência de nomenclatura por todo código. Isto é muito importante para manter o código organizado e você deve aprender fazer desde o início. Chame do mesmo nome coisas que são iguais. As variáveis de uma função estão autocontidas dentro dela e não se confundem com variáveis de outras funções. Não há risco de uma atrapalhar a outra. Portanto a variável `cli` da consulta não é a mesma variável `cli` da remoção. Aproveitei para juntar a declaração com a a atribuição do valor da variável onde dava. Também mudei a ordem dos campos. O CPF sendo chave deveria ser sempre o primeiro no cadastro.

Quando você aprender mais poderá fazer algo que parece mais sofisticado mas que na verdade é bem mais simples (não estou dizendo que deva mudar a forma no trabalho que tem que fazer agora):

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Cliente {
    public int Cpf {get; set; }
    public string Nome {get; set; }
    public int Tel {get; set; }
    public string End {get; set; }
}                

public class Program {
    static List<Cliente> ClienteList = new List<Cliente>();
                
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var op = -1;
        while (op != 0) {        
            WriteLine("Digite seu CPF (0 p/ sair)");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var consulta)) continue;
            if (consulta == 0) {
                return;
            }
            var cliente = ClienteList.Where(c => c.Cpf == consulta).FirstOrDefault();
            if (cliente != null) {
                WriteLine("Nome: " + cliente.Nome);
                WriteLine("Telefone: " + cliente.Tel);
                WriteLine("Endereco: " + cliente.End);
                WriteLine("[1 - Editar] [2 - Remover] [3 - Nova consulta] [0 - Sair]");
                if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out op)) continue;
                switch (op) {
                case 1:
                    CadastroCliente(cliente);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ClienteList.Remove(cliente);
                    WriteLine("Cadastro removido com sucesso. ");
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                var novo = new Cliente() { Cpf = consulta };
                CadastroCliente(novo);
                ClienteList.Add(novo);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void CadastroCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        WriteLine("Digite o nome: ");
        cliente.Nome = ReadLine();
        WriteLine("Digite o telefone: ");
        cliente.Tel = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        WriteLine("Digite o endereco: ");
        cliente.End = ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3AnoHn). E [no **repl.it**](https://ideone.com/XYMelv). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/FillList.cs).

Answer (score 6):

Bom, o @Maniero se adiantou, mas vou postar uma solução também, pois fiz algumas alterações principalmente na escolha das opções.

```
class Program
{
    static List<Cliente> ClienteList = new List<Cliente>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int op = -1;

        while (op != 0)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Digite 1 para cadastrar: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite 2 para consultar: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite 3 para remover cadastro");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite 4 para editar cadastro: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite 0 para sair: ");

            op = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //usar um switch/case é bem mais bonito que vários IFs aninhados
            switch (op)
            {
                case 1:
                    CadastroCliente();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ConsultaCadaCli();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    RemoverCadastro();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    EditarCliente();
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    private static void EditarCliente()
    {
        foreach(var cliente in ClienteList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cliente.Nome);
            Console.WriteLine("\"e\" para editar ou somente enter para ir para o próximo registro");
            var a = Console.ReadLine();
            if (a == "e")
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome [{0}]: ", cliente.Nome);
                var nome = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Digite o CPF [{0}]: ", cliente.Cpf);
                var cpf = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Digite o telefone [{0}]: ", cliente.Tel);
                var tel = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Digiete o endereco [{0}]: ", cliente.End);
                var end = Console.ReadLine();

                if (nome != "" && nome != cliente.Nome)
                    cliente.Nome = nome;

                if (cpf != "" && cpf != cliente.Cpf)
                    cliente.Cpf = cpf;

                if (tel != "" && tel != cliente.Tel)
                    cliente.Tel = tel;

                if (end != "" && end != cliente.End)
                    cliente.End = end;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void CadastroCliente()
    {
        Cliente cli = new Cliente();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome: ");
        cli.Nome = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o CPF: ");
        cli.Cpf = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o telefone: ");
        //o telefone tem que ser uma string
        cli.Tel = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Digiete o endereco: ");
        cli.End = Console.ReadLine();


        ClienteList.Add(cli);

    }
    public static void ConsultaCadaCli()
    {
        int Consulta;
        Console.WriteLine("Digite seu CPF");
        Consulta = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var ConsultCadastro = ClienteList.Where(c => c.Cpf.Equals(Consulta)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (ConsultCadastro != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nome: " + ConsultCadastro.Nome);
            Console.WriteLine("CPF: " + ConsultCadastro.Cpf);
            Console.WriteLine("Telefone: " + ConsultCadastro.Tel);
            Console.WriteLine("Endereco: " + ConsultCadastro.End);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cliente nao cadastrado");
        }


    }
    public static void RemoverCadastro()
    {
        int RemCadast;
        Console.WriteLine("Digite seu CPF");
        RemCadast = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var RCli = ClienteList.Where(r => r.Cpf.Equals(RemCadast)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (RCli != null)
        {
            ClienteList.Remove(RCli);
            Console.WriteLine("Cadastro removido com sucesso. ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cliente nao cadastrado");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Desta forma eu só consigo editar o primeiro cadastro.

Comment: se ficar dando enter, ele não fica trocando os registros?

Comment: Sim. Mas se forem muitos registros, terei que ficar procurando um por um?

Comment: é, o mais importante do exemplo era mostrar como tu faz pra alterar o item da lista, agora tu pode tentar aplicar alguns métodos de filtro.

Comment: o @bigown editou o exemplo dele, ta bem mais sofisticado que o meu. Só uma dúvida, qual a aplicação desse exemplo? É algum trabalho de faculdade?

Comment: É um trabalho de faculdade.

Comment: Blz então, depois comenta a nota tirada ai...

Comment: @Amanda o Pablo optou por fazer o que se chama de *browse*, vai um por um até achar o que você quer e escolhe ele para editar. O meu código eu pelo para fazer igual ao que você fez na consulta, pergunta qual você quer ver e permite editá-lo. Depois eu fiz um exemplo complementar que você pode aproveitar ou não onde todas operações foram concentradas no mesmo código já que é tudo muito parecido.

Comment: @Amanda o mais importante é fazer o que o professor pediu se formos rebuscar ao máximo os exemplos pode acontecer de fugirmos do que precisa ser feito para o problema proposto. Como é trabalho pra faculdade,  faça o simples, mas que tenha tudo o que você aprendeu até então, para que possa tirar uma boa nota.